# Конвертирование шрифтов для web

Tags: веб-программирование, шрифты

Люди, спасайте! Я уже замучился.

На одном из заказов дизайнер влепил шрифты, которые я никак не могу корректно конвертировать под веб. Пользуюсь fontsquirrel.com, шрифт DendaNew.

Он вроде конвертируется, но не качественно, размеры букв не те и как-то "пиксельно".

Может есть какие-то 100 процентные способы конвертирования?

Answer (score 1):

Вот [ресурс бесплатный](http://www.freefontconverter.com/)

А что CSS3 нельзя использовать `@font-face` ?

Comment: его ведь нельзя использовать для всех форматов. сначала надо конвертнуть

Comment: можно попробовать http://www.google.com/fonts/
здесь документация https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/getting_started?hl=ru#Quick_Start